# How to validate data on datagridview to prevent duplicate

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

for example i have "NID" as textbox and datagrid with @NID field.
i want save NID with Value "N001" to @NID on datagrid.
how to prevent duplicate when i save NID with value "N001" to datagrid.

I trying like this but error

`private sub save()
dim dgv as datagridview1
if dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).value = NID.text then
msgbox("Data duplicate")
else
dgv.rows.insert(.NewRowIndex, NID.text)
end if
end sub`

help me
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are only checking the current row of the DataGridView. You need to check all the rows.

```
'For loops are inclusive, meaning that both indexes will be reached.
'dgv.Rows is a zero indexed collection so "dgv.Rows(dgv.RowCount)" would give an error
For i = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1 

    If dgv.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = NID.Text
        MsgBox("Duplicate data")
        Exit Sub 'So no insert occurs
    End If

Next
'code to insert row
```

Comment: i use this code  `If Not IsDBNull(dataspdibeli.Rows(i).Cells("NID_SP").Value) AndAlso dataspdibeli.Rows(i).Cells("NID_SP").Value = spnid.Text Then`   but the both code have same function..  thanks